# i can not logout in my project , in tutorial of cakephp.org

Tags: cakephp, acl, logout

i follow cakephp tutorial and when i log in to my account,
link of tutorial is :
http://book.cakephp.org/view/1543/Simple-Acl-controlled-Application
, i can't logout :
my code in logout method is

```
    function logout() {
    $this->Session->setFlash('Good-Bye');
    $this->redirect($this->Auth->logout());
}
```

and login code is :

```
    function login() {

    if ($this->Session->read('Auth.User')) {
        $this->Session->setFlash('You are logged in!');
        $this->redirect('/', null, false);
    }
}
```

this method is inside of users_controller .
but when i use this URL

```
http://localhost/newacl/users/logout
```

i comeback in

```
http://localhost/newacl/users
```

and i view this text

## *You are logged in!*

therefore i can't log out.
can you say what is happen and say what the work am i doing.

Comment: Are you using the latest version of Cake? There was a bug in one of the releases of 1.3.

Comment: i use cakephp 1.3.13 and this is example of cakephp.org that use cake 1.3

Comment: Could you post your ACL config (in the before_filter in your app_controller). This might be a redirect issue where the user is logged out and logged in again..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its problem of you redirect thing you logout ..Add below code in your App_controller.php beforeFilter

```
$this->Auth->loginError = "Wrong credentials. Please provide a valid username and password.";

            $this->Auth->authError = "You don't have sufficient privilege to access this resource.";

            $this->Auth->loginAction = array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login');

            $this->Auth->logoutRedirect = array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login');

            $this->Auth->loginRedirect = array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'home');
```

In you r logout

```
 $this->Session->setFlash('You Succefully Logged Out');
         $this->Auth->logout(); 
         $this->redirect('/');
```

in your login try this

```
if($this->Auth->user('id')){
     $this->Session->setFlash('You are logged in!');
      $this->redirect('/', null, false);
}
```

hope this may help you....

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old topic, but maybe it'll be helpful for others.

It seems that adding this

```
function beforeFilter() {
 $this->Auth->allow('login','logout');
}
```

to UsersController resolves the problem with logout